# Comparing the characters

Tags: c, char

I am writing a code for solving arithmetic expression like:`4+3-2*6*(3+4/2)`

For that I need to compare the operators in the string with precedence like:

```
1. ( or )
2. * or /
3. + or -
```

Can someone tell me how to compare two characters. As their ASCII values are not in the order which I want!

Comment: why not just make your own comparison function?

Comment: Yupp I could do that but I was looking if there is some other efficient way to do it! Like I could define my ascii values for the operators ,,I know this is not possible but something similar to that..

Comment: Also .. The eg. of arithmetic expression which I gave in the que. is just a simple version. More complex arithmetic expression could involve other abstract operators like '$' ,'%', '^', '@', '&' etc. with their operation defined on two integers and precedence over other operators. You can't just make a function for this !! It'd take 100's of lines to write that function ..(think of selection of 3 operators to compare from n operators)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lookup table. If using ASCII, it is just a 256 element table. You index it with the char.

Comment: what do u mean by saying.. 'index it with char'.. please elaborate it!

Comment: if you have a char in a variable `c` and your array is `A`, just do `A[c]` to get the character's precedence.

Comment: what if I have to give two or more operators same precedence .. This won't work in that case.. Read my 3rd comment in the que.!

Comment: why not? Two different positions on the array can have the same value.

Comment: Recommend code uses unsigned indexing `A[c*1u]`.  Issues arise when `char` is signed.

Comment: If using ASCII, only 128 elements are needed.

Answer (score 2):

> For that I need to compare the operators in the string with precedence
>   like:

You can do something like this to get a precedence for each character:

```
int get_precedence (char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case '+':
        case '-': return 3;

        case '*':
        case '/': return 2;

        case '(':
        case ')': return 1;

        default: return -1;
    }
}
```

That makes it very easy to add in additonal characters as you need.

However, you'll still have some issues. For example, how will you tell unary negation from subtraction? You'll need to look at context for that, because the answer will depend on what comes before. Dealing with infix notation is *hard*.

To do this yourself, you'll want to write a [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) or use the [shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). Either way, it'll be several hundred lines of *hard* code. Then you'll need to decide if you evaluate from the abstract syntax tree or compile to byte code.

> I am writing a code for solving arithmetic expression
>   like:`4+3-2*6*(3+4/2)`

If you want to solve that in an easy way, you should find a pre-existing library. [TinyExpr](https://github.com/codeplea/tinyexpr) is one such solution. It's open-source and contained in a single C source code file. Code for that would look like:

```
#include "tinyexpr.h"
double answer = te_interp("4+3-2*6*(3+4/2)", 0);
```

Comment: Nice first time answer.  IMO, the best one.

Answer (score 1):

Even in ASCII, the order of the integers are still the same. You can compare single digits. For example:

`if ('7' > '2')` will evaluate to true